# insert a dynamic value inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have a range slider and i want its `max value` to be set equal to `value` of the `id="form-prezzo"` input. This last value is dynamically generated.

Is this even possible?

I don't know how to set the `max:$form("prezzo").val,`

here's my code

```js
const $mutuo = $("#mutuo"),
      $rata = $("#rata"),
      $anni = $("#anni"),
      $slider1 = $("#slider1"),
      $slider2 = $("#slider2"),
      $max = $("#prova");

    function update() {
      let interesseannuo = 1.60,
        C = $("#form-prezzo").val(),
        anni = $anni.val(),
        i = interesseannuo / 12 / 100,
        n = anni * 12,
        rata = C * i / (1 - Math.pow(1 + i, -n));

      $rata.html(rata.toFixed(2) + " €");
    }

    $slider1.slider({
      //max: 100000-(100000/100*20),
      max: $max.html(),
      min: 0,
      step: 10,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        $mutuo.val(ui.value);
        update();
      }
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>





<div class="info-paragraph black" id="prova">1000</div>
<p class="info-paragraph black">Totale mutuo (€)</p>
<div id="slider1"></div>
<input class="info-paragraph black" type="text" id="mutuo" value="0"><br>
```

Comment: What you're doing looks correct, you just need to make sure the value is put in by the php before you try to make the slider.

Comment: unfortunately it did not work, i've put this script and the input under the php. in fact the same value is rendered correctly from php.. but this script doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `max: $("#form-prezzo").val()` is not working, I think it is because of the returned value of `$("#form-prezzo").val()` that is of type `String`.

Try `max: parseInt($("#form-prezzo").val())` or `max: parseFloat($("#form-prezzo").val())` and see if it works.

Comment: neither the first and the second solution works unfortunately... it's so strange- Maybe there's another way to display some content inside the max value? like show the dynamic contend in the html of a div and recall that: max: parseInt($("#anotherID").html())

Comment: In [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zh7c3wdv/4/), I tried your code, manually typed a number in place of `(some dynamic php value)` and it **worked just fine**. Maybe that `$slider1.slider({max: $("#form-prezzo").val().....` code is being executed **before** the `<input type="hidden" id="form-prezzo"...` element is loaded into DOM? Try enclosing your javascript in a `$(function(){ //your code here })` that gets executed only after DOM content is loaded.

Comment: same.. if I add some number in the parenthesis it works, but if I try to display other than a specific number it stops. i've updated my post with a different solution.. I've created a div with `id="prova"` and this id show a correct dynamic content. but even if I put a static number and I try to pass it with `parseInt($("#prova").html())` to the `max:` it doesn't work

Comment: The updated code in your question **works as expected**. Where is the problem now? I cannot understand the `but even if I put a static number and I try to pass it with ...  it doesn't work` part. What exactly do you mean by *doesn't work*? Can you link a JSFiddle? Now I am also suspicious that the php script may be the culprit.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake when I wrote the comment.. I mean that it works well with static number, but when I try to read a dynamic value it stops.. here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5fjzt0me/9/).. I don't think it's a php problem because in the jsfiddle example I'm trying to get the `max` value from the div with `id="max"`.. I'm getting mad..

Comment: In [this](https://jsfiddle.net/5fjzt0me/9/) JSFiddle you posted, remove the ` <div class="info-paragraph black" id="max" value="1234213"></div>` and put `<input type="hidden" class="info-paragraph black" id="max" value="1234213"></input>` there. [Now it works.](https://jsfiddle.net/5fjzt0me/16/) It seems that `$.val()` doesn't work on `div` elements.

So, you have to change it to either `<input type="hidden" id="myid">` and `$max = $('#myid').val();`

OR if you need it to be it a `div`, use it like `<div id="myid" value="1245"></div>` and get it as `$max = $('#myid').attr('value');`.